# Angular. Route relative to object id: how to do it if the component is showed with two URL?

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

My problem is the following one.
Here's my route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'tasks', component : TodoListComponent},
  { path: 'tasks/:id', component : SingleTaskComponent},
  { path: '', component : TodoListComponent},
];
```

When I navigate from url/tasks to url/tasks/id, everything works well.
But when I do it from url/, it doesn't work (obviously) because it redirect to url/id because there is this button in the TodoListComponent template :

```
<a [routerLink]="id">Edit</a>
```

Do you know how could I manage that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use redirectTo option:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', redirectTo: 'tasks', pathMatch:'full'}
  { path: 'tasks', component : TodoListComponent},
  { path: 'tasks/:id', component : SingleTaskComponent},
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', redirectTo: 'task', pathMatch:'full'}
  { path: 'tasks', component : TodoListComponent},
  { path: 'tasks/:id', component : SingleTaskComponent},
  { path: '', component : TodoListComponent},
];

component.ts
goList(){
this.router.navigate(['/tasks'])
}

component.html
<a routerLink="tasks" class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active">edit</a>
// active is Boolean value - declare in .ts file
```